# Postgres - Loop through nested, inconsistent Jsonb array and extract value where another key = "X"

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb object which looks like :

```
{"result" : {
 "address_components": [
      {
        "types": ["route"],
        "long_name": "Church Road",
        "short_name": "Church Rd"
      },
      {
        "types": ["administrative_area_level_1","political"],
        "long_name": "England",
        "short_name": "England"
      },
      {
        "types": ["country", "political"],
        "long_name": "United Kingdom",
        "short_name": "GB"
      },
      {
        "types": [ "postal_code"],
        "long_name": "TS18 1TW",
        "short_name": "TS18 1TW"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a SELECT query that pulls through the `types ->> 0` as the column name, and the `long_name` as the value, but not for every 'type'. So for example if I just want the 'route', 'postal_code' and 'country', the result might look like:

```
route       | postal_code | country
Church Road | TS18 1TW.   | United Kingdom
```

I've tried using `jsonb_array_elements` but that only returns the first sub-array. Adding to the complexity is that the `address_components` json doesn't always contain i.e. a `route` array, and so I can't just pull through i.e. the first array and name it 'route'.

[db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/2630)

Of course this is nowhere near complete, but I'm not sure where to go from here. How do I make "route" the column name and "Church Road" the value, but also for "country" and "postal_code" if they exist?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to upgrade to v12 then use jsonpath methods such as.

```
jsonb_path_query_first(
   full_response,
   '$.result.address_components[*] ? (@.types[0]=="route").long_name'
)
```

for example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/2633

Comment: Is there any solution that doesn't involve upgrading ?